# Cannot download from WebDav Error 0x80070780

Tags: windows-10, webdav

I setup WebDAV on a Win10 machine (server).  From another Win10 machine (client) I mapped to the server via "Add a network location" in windows explorer.  This successfully created the connection.  I can list files, upload files, create directories, see file attributes.  **However**, when I attempt to download a file (i.e. on the client I attempt to retrieve a file *from* the WebDAV server) I get the following error: `Error 0x80070780: The file cannot be accessed by the system`.

Researching this error I've found lots of information about this error when attempting to upload to the server, but nothing about when downloading.

I expect this is an issue with Win10 on the client because I'm able to download with 3rd party software (Cyberduck).  I get the same error on a different Win10 machine as well.

Other details:

- Connection is https
- I have a valid certificate from Let's Encrypt
- The connection is to a sub domain and sub folder (e.g. `https://sub.mydomain.com/webdav`)
- User logs into a local (to the server) account

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this was actually on the server side.  For some reason Explorer requires the permission "Source" while the 3rd party software doesn't.  **I'd be love to see another answer explain why this is.**

To set this permission:

1. Open IIS Mananger
2. Select the WebDAV site or folder
3. Open "WebDAV Authoring Rules"
4. Edit the pertinent rule
5. Ensure the "Source" box is ticked and click "OK"